# Optimization converged but frequency calculation does not

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian

I tried a three-step job file for gaussian. This is my input file:

```
%chk=start_struc.chk
%mem=50GB
%nprocshared=8
#p opt=calcall ub3lyp/6-31g(2df,p) empiricaldispersion=gd3bj nosymm guess=always integral=grid=superfine test

Titel

Molecular Specification

--Link1--
%oldchk=start_struc.chk
%chk=start_struc_stab.chk
%mem=20GB
%nprocshared=8
# stable=opt UHF/6-31g(2df,p) geom=check

Titel 

Charge/Multi

--Link1--
%oldchk=start_struc_stab.chk
%chk=start_struc_freq.chk
%mem=80GB
%nprocshared=8

Title 

Charge/Multi
```

The calculation worked and I got an log file that says: `Normal termination of Gaussian 16 at`

So my problem is that in the optimization I got convergence at the end of the calculation. But in the frequency calculation after the stability check, the structure does not converge anymore? Do I make a systematic mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the stability check reveal an instability?

Comment: Your system can be trapped in a saddle point.

Comment: A `opt=calcall` calculation will perform frequency analysis at the converged geometry, since it already computes the Hessian at every step. Did both frequency calcs fail or just the one after the stability calc?

Comment: @wzkchem5 no the wavefunction is stable

Comment: @Tyberius this is the strange thing. The optimization with the freqs does not fail just the frequency calculation at the end

Comment: @Andrea What do you mean by "the structure does not converge anymore" in the frequency calculation? Do you mean that the RMS step and/or MAX step that are printed after the frequency calculation are larger than the convergence thresholds?

Comment: @wzkchem5 I mean this part after the frequencies printed out:`Item               Value     Threshold  Converged?
Maximum Force            0.008372     0.000450     NO 
RMS     Force            0.001138     0.000300     NO 
Maximum Displacement     0.419115     0.001800     NO 
RMS     Displacement     0.115345     0.001200     NO `

Comment: It's strange that even the gradients did not converge. Is the input geometry of the frequency calculation (as judged from the output file) the same as the last geometry of the geometry optimization? If yes, do their SCF energies agree?

Comment: @Andrea in the absence of an answer to wzkchem5's question, this post would unfortunately have to be closed due to lacking necessary details.